# B2B / B2C, as one or two separate websites?

Tags: website-design, information-architecture, users, target-users

I'm in the middle of re-designing our company website and have found myself in a pinch when it comes dividing the site into B2C / B2B. (I've seen the other thread about this topic but didn't think it answered my question.)

Here's my situation:
Our primary target user is B2C (in our case, people looking for/signing up for clinical studies). The landing page will oriented towards this user group.

Our secondary target user is business, which are interested in the users which register on our B2C page.

What I'm having a hard time deciding is how to structure the webpage. Should I structure it as two separate websites or as one (with a B2C landing page)from which a B2B user can go to the relevant page? Seesite map sketches below:

As two separate sites:
[image]

Or as one site with B2B as a subpage:
[image]

I would prefer the two site approach but I'm concerned with how to make the nav clear for B2C users if they accidentally land on the B2B page. (Since they are patients looking for studies, I don't feel comfortable with referring to them as 'customers', neither do I think that they will understand that a 'customers' link will get them to the B2C page.... A copy issue I guess...

On the other hand, if a B2B user lands on the B2C page (which is fine) and finds his way to the B2B page, where does the 'Home' button send him? To the home of B2B or B2C?

[image]
[image]

I've done some minor testing and found that this was confusing for both target users... 
What do?

Comment: Financial Services sites have this dilemma eg https://www.hsbc.co.uk.  They also tend to hide the corporate stuff away under a link down at the bottom of the main site.

Answer (score 1):

I have met, designed and prefer the first option where you separate the two sites, especially for back-end it's a clear division (less misunderstandings will occur between you and tech in development phase).

However in communication it has to be in the first contact for both B2C & B2B:

-home page: if you communicate both the user will understand that you are not a (1) pharma, but there can be more who cowork with this platform. Therefore there would be no misunderstandings.

- TOP menu:
  neither 1 or 2 is good:

because always show 2 options, so that a pharma can see how the students( i guess) site looks like, and students might have the opportunity to see who can join this platform, they want to check if there can be anyone or just the best ones.

so on the top bar place, always :

**Participate in studies = I want to study
&
Pharma offering studies = I give studies opportunities**

so that a user can switch between both, like switch off/on

if one is chosen> communicate it by making less optiality of the chosen switch"

and don't play with the home button, if user afer he 7s of looking at the homepage "click and run in the wrong place on your web site without understanding it, so that he can always go back with **"logo"- home button to the homepage for B2B & B2C**

This solution is now useful and flexible for every site view and you can create just one master and place it everywhere.

Additionally:

If pharma (user) wont be an active user (if i understood right, you mean that pharma will be administrated, but additionally pharma can log in to the platform to see the conversations with students? CVs? or what?)

the question is, 
why should they register?

If there is no reason, make a informational LP with an easy way to contact your administrators > 1 clear call to action > start > get in contact with us.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Indeed, I am leaning more towards the two-site solution. I've thought about the toggle/switch metaphor between the user groups, though that would still need a change in the the top menu depending on which user the visitor is. (I.e not showing the 'pharma user' studies since they won't be participating in them, but administrating them).

Comment: Answear with an additional question in my ansear above:)

Comment: Let Us know & see how your reluts look like!

Answer (score -2):

You might want to separate the two site as your b2c customers might not what to feel like cattle to your b2b consumers...

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The relationship between the two is beneficial, i.e both have to take part of our services (but from different ends) to connect with each other, thus I doubt that the 'customers' will feel like cattle. Though I am leaning more towards the two site solution. :-)